# CentOS 8 stream module conflicts installing package

Tags: yum, dependencies, dnf, appstream

I'm trying to install the redhat-lsb package.  This will allow me to gather additional facts when running ansible against this target machine.

When I attempt to install redhat-lsb I get the following output:

```
yum install redhat-lsb
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:12 ago on Thu 02 Jun 2022 08:19:04 PM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: package redhat-lsb-4.1-47.el8.x86_64 requires redhat-lsb-languages = 4.1-47.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package redhat-lsb-languages-4.1-47.el8.i686 requires perl(Fatal), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package redhat-lsb-languages-4.1-47.el8.x86_64 requires perl(Fatal), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - package perl-autodie-2.34-1.module_el8.6.0+1070+343f8e3c.noarch is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

It appears to have an issue with perl-autodie.  So then I ran the command "yum module provides perl-autodie".  Here's the results:

```
yum module provides perl-autodie
Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:38 ago on Thu 02 Jun 2022 08:19:04 PM UTC.
perl-autodie-2.34-1.module_el8.6.0+1070+343f8e3c.noarch
Module   : perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1:x86_64
Profiles : 
Repo     : centos8-stream-appstream
Summary  : Practical Extraction and Report Language
```

Based on the results, perl-autodie is available in the perl:5.32 module.  So then I enable the perl:5.32 module with the command "yum module enable perl:5.32", and check the results with "yum module list perl".  Here's the results:

```
# yum module enable perl:5.32
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:06 ago on Thu 02 Jun 2022 08:19:04 PM UTC.
Problems in request:
Modular dependency problems with Defaults:

 Problem: module perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64
  - module perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64
  - module freeradius:3.0:8030020200831192931:1e4bbb35.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
Dependencies resolved.
============================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Architecture                    Version                            Repository                        Size
============================================================================================================================================
Enabling module streams:
 perl                                                             5.32                                                                     

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================

Is this ok [y/N]: y
Complete!
# yum module list perl
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:21 ago on Thu 02 Jun 2022 08:19:04 PM UTC.
Modular dependency problem:

 Problem: module perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64
  - module perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64
  - module freeradius:3.0:8030020200831192931:1e4bbb35.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
CentOS-Stream 8 AppStream
Name                  Stream                    Profiles                            Summary                                                 
perl                  5.24                      common [d], minimal                 Practical Extraction and Report Language                
perl                  5.26 [d]                  common [d], minimal                 Practical Extraction and Report Language                
perl                  5.30                      common [d], minimal                 Practical Extraction and Report Language                
perl                  5.32 [e]                  common [d], minimal                 Practical Extraction and Report Language                

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

Now we can see the perl:5.26 is still the default and perl:5.32 is enabled.  With perl:5.32 enabled, I can only assume that the perl-autodie dependency will be satisfied and availalbe.  If I attempt to install redhat-lsb now, I get the following output:

```
# yum install redhat-lsb
Last metadata expiration check: 0:16:42 ago on Thu 02 Jun 2022 08:19:04 PM UTC.
Modular dependency problem:

 Problem: module perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64
  - module perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64
  - module freeradius:3.0:8030020200831192931:1e4bbb35.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
Error: 
 Problem: package redhat-lsb-core-4.1-47.el8.x86_64 requires /usr/bin/lp, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package redhat-lsb-core-4.1-47.el8.x86_64 requires /usr/bin/lpr, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package redhat-lsb-4.1-47.el8.x86_64 requires redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-47.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-client-1:2.2.6-46.el8.x86_64 requires cups-libs(x86-64) = 1:2.2.6-46.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - package cups-libs-1:2.2.6-46.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by exclude filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

It looks like the freeradius module is dependent on the perl:5.26 module, but the perl:5.32 modules is the one that's enabled.  I don't need freeradius, so let's just remove it with, "yum module remove freeradius:3.0:8030020200831192931:1e4bbb35.x86_64"

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:20:09 ago on Thu 02 Jun 2022 08:19:04 PM UTC.
Modular dependency problem:

 Problem: module perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64
  - module perl:5.32:8060020220119032749:e82d91b1.x86_64 conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64
  - module freeradius:3.0:8030020200831192931:1e4bbb35.x86_64 requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
Problems in request:
missing groups or modules: freeradius:3.0:8030020200831192931:1e4bbb35.x86_64
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I'm completely stuck in appstream modular repository hell.  All I want to do is install redhat-lsb.  I'm stuck at this point and am begging for help.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I have similar issues on Oracle Linux 8. No solution so far.

Comment: dnf module remove freeradius:3.0 should fix the issue with freeradius

Answer (score -1):

Run `yum distro-sync` should resolve issue.